# Java spring jpa incorrect profile link

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I am following the instructions found in this [link](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-rest) in order to create an application that connects to a db2 server. Instead of defining a `Person` class, I want to use my `Accounts` class, which is the name of my table. The key field in my table is a string of `varchar(255)` type, so I defined it like this:

```java
@Id
String id;
```

I did not use the `@GeneratedValue` annotation because the id is not generated by the database.

Here is the repository I defined:

```java
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "accounts", path = "accounts")
public interface AccountsRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Accounts, String>, CrudRepository<Accounts, String> {
    List<Accounts> findByLastName(String lastName);
    Optional<Accounts> findById(String id);
}
```

When I run the application and try to connect to `localhost:8080`, I get the following response:

```
{
  "_links" : {
    "profile" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/profile"
    }
  }
}
```

The result is that I cannot use the link http://localhost:8080/accounts. I will be grateful for any suggestions on how to solve this. Thanks! :-)